# How to add a fadein effect to new images?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I add a smooth fadeIn effect to the new images?

```
var switchImage = function(newImageSrc, newImage, mainImageDomEl) {
  jQuery(mainImageDomEl).attr('src', newImageSrc);
  $(mainImageDomEl).parents('a').attr('href', newImageSrc);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use jQUery `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` functions, see example below.

```js
var switchImage = function(newImageSrc, newImage, mainImageDomEl) {
  $(mainImageDomEl).fadeOut(200, function() {
      $(mainImageDomEl).attr('src', newImageSrc);
      $(mainImageDomEl).fadeIn(200);
  });
};

var images = [
  'http://cdn.morguefile.com/imageData/public/files/n/Natureworks/03/l/139404735343e9t.jpg',
  'http://cdn.morguefile.com/imageData/public/files/p/pippalou/04/l/1398366305gv9cc.jpg'
];

var i=0;
setInterval(function() {
   var parent = $('div');
   switchImage(images[i], null, $('img'));
   i = (i+1)%images.length;
}, 2000);
```

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img src="http://cdn.morguefile.com/imageData/public/files/p/pippalou/04/l/1398366305gv9cc.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In jquery you can use function `fadeIn()` or `fadeOut()`. Refer to this for more.  [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)